# Repeating the last move using . (w followed by .)

Tags: macvim, repeated-commands

I read that `.` is used for repeating the last command in Normal Mode. So if I used the command `2w` move forward two words and then press `.` then I would expect to move two words more however this does not happen.

Could anyone please tell me why ?

Comment: Where did you read that `.` repeats the last command? Not in `:help .`, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [`:h .`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#.) the dot command only repeat changes, but commands like `w` are motions not changes.

You can repeat motions like `f`, `F`, `t` and `T` with the commands `;` and `g;` (see [`:h ;`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#;)). And for more complex repeat you could have a look to the easymotion plugin [readme](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion#repeat-motions): combined with [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) you might be able to repeat the movements the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Vim answers this in the [help about the dot command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#.):

```
.           Repeat last change, with count replaced with [count].
            Also repeat a yank command, when the 'y' flag is
            included in 'cpoptions'.  Does not repeat a
            command-line command.
```

So `.` simply repeats the last *change*, not motions, or command-line commands.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to "repeat the last motion command", though?

Comment: @Wildcard: for `f`, `F`, `t` and `T` motion you can use `;` ([`:h ;`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#;))